# Can doc2vec training result could change with same input data, and same parameter?

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I'm using Doc2Vec in gensim library, and finding similiarity between movie, with its name as input.

```
model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=100, alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.025, window=5)
model.build_vocab(tagged_corpus_list)
model.train(tagged_corpus_list, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=50)
```

I set parameter like this, and didn't change preprocessing mechanism of input data, didn't changed original data.

```
similar_doc = model.dv.most_similar(input)
```

I also used this code to find most similar movie.
When I restarted code to train this model, the most similar movie has changed, with changed score.
Is this possible? Why? If then, how can I fix the training result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this sort of change from run to run is normal. It's well-explained in question 11 of the Gensim FAQ:

> #### [Q11: I've trained my `Word2Vec` / `Doc2Vec` / etc model repeatedly using the exact same text corpus, but the vectors are different each time. Is there a bug or have I made a mistake? (*2vec training non-determinism)](https://github.com/RARE-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Recipes-&-FAQ#q11-ive-trained-my-word2vec--doc2vec--etc-model-repeatedly-using-the-exact-same-text-corpus-but-the-vectors-are-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-2vec-training-non-determinism)
>
> **Answer:** The *2vec models (word2vec, fasttext, doc2vec…) begin with random initialization, then most modes use additional randomization
> during training. (For example, the training windows are randomly
> truncated as an efficient way of weighting nearer words higher. The
> negative examples in the default negative-sampling mode are chosen
> randomly. And the downsampling of highly-frequent words, as controlled
> by the `sample` parameter, is driven by random choices. These
> behaviors were all defined in the original Word2Vec paper's algorithm
> description.)
>
> Even when all this randomness comes from a
> pseudorandom-number-generator that's been seeded to give a
> reproducible stream of random numbers (which gensim does by default),
> the usual case of multi-threaded training can further change the exact
> training-order of text examples, and thus the final model state.
> (Further, in Python 3.x, the hashing of strings is randomized each
> re-launch of the Python interpreter - changing the iteration ordering
> of vocabulary dicts from run to run, and thus making even the same
> string-of-random-number-draws pick different words in different
> launches.)
>
> So, it is to be expected that models vary from run to run, even
> trained on the same data. There's no single "right place" for any
> word-vector or doc-vector to wind up: just positions that are at
> progressively more-useful distances & directions from other vectors
> co-trained inside the same model. (In general, only vectors that were
> trained together in an interleaved session of contrasting uses become
> comparable in their coordinates.)
>
> Suitable training parameters should yield models that are roughly as
> useful, from run-to-run, as each other. Testing and evaluation
> processes should be tolerant of any shifts in vector positions, and of
> small "jitter" in the overall utility of models, that arises from the
> inherent algorithm randomness. (If the observed quality from
> run-to-run varies a lot, there may be other problems: too little data,
> poorly-tuned parameters, or errors/weaknesses in the evaluation
> method.)
>
> You can try to force determinism, by using `workers=1` to limit
> training to a single thread – and, if in Python 3.x, using the
> `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable to disable its usual string hash
> randomization. But training will be much slower than with more
> threads. And, you'd be obscuring the inherent
> randomness/approximateness of the underlying algorithms, in a way that
> might make results more fragile and dependent on the luck of a
> particular setup. It's better to tolerate a little jitter, and use
> excessive jitter as an indicator of problems elsewhere in the data or
> model setup – rather than impose a superficial determinism.

If the change between runs is small – nearest neighbors mostly the same, with a few in different positions – it's best to tolerate it.

If the change is big, there's likely some other problem, like insufficient training data or poorly-chosen parameters.

Notably, `min_alpha=0.025` isn't a sensible value - the training is supposed to use a gradually-decreasing value, and the usual default (`min_alpha=0.0001`) usually doesn't need changing. (If you copied this from an online example: that's a bad example! Don't trust that site unless it explains why it's doing an odd thing.)

Increasing the number of training epochs, from the default `epochs=5` to something like `10` or `20` may also help make run-to-run results more consistent, especially if you don't have plentiful training data.